# Integrate Solr & Mahout

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, mahout, recommendation-engine

Solr/Lucene provides the relevancy score for a fulltext search, and Mahout provides recommendations of items for a user along with the preference score.

Right now I have both Solr and Mahout working seperately: When a user searches for a query string, Solr handles the searching and returns the 10 results according to its score. How can I integrate both Mahout and Solr together to provide the top 10 results or next 10 results according to another scoring system (like 0.5*Solr's score + 0.5*Mahout's score).

**Problem:** Right now it seems to be suboptimal doing the initial search for say the 11th to 20th item sorted by the new scoring, Solr will have to fetch the scores for all items in its database, and Mahout fetch the score for all items in its data base, calculate the resultant score and resort.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What kind of recommendations are you doing with mahout? user-based or item-based? My thoughts are: for item-based recommendations (if they are not too many), you can create the item similarity matrix, then index that into solr (daily or whenever), then all your queries go directly to solr where you will get the user taste vector and use solr to do the recommendations (in addition to any other scoring system you already have in solr)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding your score from mahout as an additional field in Solr, and then perhaps using sort query, "boost_field desc", this will then allow you to use mahouts score, ... to combine, you may be able to use a field boost such as ^ ... -

its not really a full answer but may lead you to something better.